# Twitter Bootstrap inclusion issue

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2013

I am having some trouble showing Bootstrap components on my page in a Visual Studio using Asp.Net MVC 5. I am using these examples [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns) for the drop down and [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups) for the button groups.

This is what the page looks like:

[image]

This is the page source that gets generated

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>NewIndex</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/justified-nav.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    New Index page

    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn dropdown-toggle sr-only" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Dropdown
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <br />

    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

All of the referenced files are there in their respective paths. Any idea on what could be wrong?

Comment: Your ".css" are not added correct on page. Because you are using the "<script></script>" tag for this. You should use <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=""> .

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment :

You should add CSS file with [`link`](http://www.csstutorial.net/css_misc_inserting.php) tag, instead of `<script></script>` block. Script block is used for adding the `Javascript`.

Adding External Style Sheet (CSS) on your web page:

> Each page must include a link to the style sheet with the  tag.
>   The  tag goes inside the head section:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourstyle.css">
</head>
```

Try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/site.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/justified-nav.css" />
```

According to the **@cvrebert** comment, You must include the Jquery library references (`jquery-1.10.2.js`) before the other javascript files. the correct order of the Script File is:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
```

As i mentioned above you must put your `link` tag into head section. So the correct HTML of page look like this -

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>NewIndex</title>
    <!--Your CSS Style Sheets-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/justified-nav.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <!--Your Script Files-->
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
    <div> 
        New Index page
        <br />
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
            <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header</li>
            ...
            <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header</li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </div>


    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn dropdown-toggle sr-only" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Dropdown
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks that worked only for the button group. The drop down menu doesnt seem to be working

Comment: @user20358: Please check browser console. Any error? OR Check the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BqKNV/310/

Comment: the console says bootstrap requires Juery. but I already have a reference to it..

Comment: It works in jsfiddle, but there I am using jquery-1.10.1.js. My code has jquery-1.10.2.js.. Could that be the problem? It shouldnt be ideally.

Comment: @user20358: Accually i did't have any experience with Jquery- 1.10.2.js. So, I am not able to tell you these things. Sorry... But it's working with Jquery 1.10.1.js . See http://jsfiddle.net/BqKNV/312/. (I think, you should try this once)

Comment: @user20358: The `<script>` for jQuery must come **before** the one for Bootstrap. Your original example has the order backwards.

Comment: @cvrebert: Yes, you are right. First include the Jquery library references and after including the other javascript files - is the right way. Thank for your valuable suggestion. :)

Comment: I changed the script tag to come before. Still no change. Is there something wrong in the code? The console shows an error: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'sendMEssage'

Comment: @user20358: it's related to "sendMEssage" method. ("sendMEssage" method not found on page)

Comment: There is no send message method on my page. The code above is the full page source. Is it something to do with the bootstrap library?

Comment: @user20358: As you said : "There is no send message method on my page", But the "sendMEssage" call form some-where on page or js. So, it's throw error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55173/discussion-between-ishan-jain-and-user20358).

Comment: @user20358: you could accept my answer as a correct answer !! :) Because it can help may other users to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Change your bootstrap.css references from script tags to link tags.. example:

```
<link href="../Styles/mystyle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: thanks that worked only for the button group. The drop down menu doesnt seem to be working .